# How to get a numpy ndarray of integers from a file with header?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a plain text file (.txt) with the following content.

```
Matrix Header.
6 11
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 

 6 rows,  11 columns
```

I need obtain a numpy ndarray of integers as below:

```
[[0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] 
 [1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1] 
 [1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1] 
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0] 
 [1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1] 
 [1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0]]
```

I tried the following strategy

```
import pandas
import numpy
data = pandas.read_table(path, skiprows= 2)
data = data.values
print(data)
```

But the resulting ndarray isn't in the correct format.

```
[['0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 '] 
 ['1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 '] 
 ['1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 '] 
 ['0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 '] 
 ['1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 '] 
 ['1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 ']]
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You need to use `sep=' '` in `read_table()`. You could also use directly `numpy.load_txt()`.

Comment: Does your input file actually contain the text `6 rows,  11 columns` at the bottom?

Comment: Works fine, thanks @JulienBernu. Have any suggestions for a more elegant and efficient implementation?

Comment: Yes in some files and this is causing an error. Have any suggestions for correction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the error that might occur because of the text at the end, you can use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) with the `max_rows` argument.  For example,

```
In [26]: with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    ...:     f.readline()  # skip the header
    ...:     nrows, ncols = [int(field) for field in f.readline().split()]
    ...:     data = np.genfromtxt(f, dtype=int, max_rows=nrows)
    ...:     

In [27]: data
Out[27]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

(I opened the file in binary mode to avoid a bytes/str problem that `genfromtxt` has in Python 3.)

Comment: Thanks Warren. Excellent solution.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to explicitly ignore the lines you don't need:

```
with open(path) as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
np.loadtxt(lines[2:-2])
del lines # if you want to immediately release the memory
```

This directly gives you what you want, assuming the header and footer are always two lines each.